# use .apply() function to change values to a column of the dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is the following:

[image]

and I would like to consider only the column of instructions and keep just the values push, test, mov, test ,....., so just the first word of each string inside each list. What I am doing is the following:

```
dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['instructions'].apply(instruction.split()[0] for instruction in dataFrame['instructions'])
```

but I get the following message:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

so, my objective is to change the values only of the column instructions.

Can somebody please help me? Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you dataframe is `data`, use the below `apply()` function:

**For column with list of words separated by space:**

```
data['New_instructions'] = data['instructions'].apply(lambda x: [i.split()[0].strip()for i in x])
```

**For column with single list word:**

```
data['New_instructions'] = data['instructions'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0].strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

use lambda function like as follows

```
dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['instructions'].apply(lambda x:[i.split()[0] for i in x])
```